# onclick listener not working in surfaceview of swipe layout

Tags: java, android, swipe

I am trying to call constructor on `onClick` listener of `getSurfaceView` for swipe layout but it is not happening.

```
RideAdapter.java

@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
View view; 
if (viewType == RIDE_ITEM_TYPE) {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_upcoming_share_ride, parent, false);
      swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sample2);
      swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);
      swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, swipeLayout.findViewWithTag("Bottom2"));
//        sample2.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);
      swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Star", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });`



  swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Magnifier", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });

  swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_upcoming_share_ride, parent, false);
      new OfferedRideCardViewHolder(v);
    }
  });


  return new OfferedRideCardViewHolder(view);
```

and `OfferedRideCardViewHolder` class:

```
class OfferedRideCardViewHolder extends BaseRideViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.imgVechicleImage) ImageView imgVechicle;
    @BindView(R.id.imgRideIcon) ImageView imgRideIcon;
    @BindView(R.id.fromTextView) TextView txtFromLocation;
    @BindView(R.id.toTextView) TextView txtToLocation;
    @BindView(R.id.txtVichecleModel) TextView txtVichecleModel;
    @BindView(R.id.txtRegisterationNo) TextView txtRegisterationNo;
    @BindView(R.id.txtDateTime) TextView txtDateTime;
    @BindView(R.id.buttonStartEnd) Button startEndRideButton;
    @BindView(R.id.matchCountTextView) TextView matchCountTextView;
    @BindView(R.id.matchesTextView) TextView matchesTextView;
    @BindView(R.id.vehicleContainer) LinearLayout vehicleContainer;

    OfferedRideCardViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
```

item_upcoming_share_ride.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

  <com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
      android:id="@+id/sample2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:tag="Bottom2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/edit"
          android:src="@drawable/edit"
          android:layout_width="70dp"
          android:background="#00FF00"
          android:paddingLeft="25dp"
          android:paddingRight="25dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/delete"
          android:src="@drawable/delete_grey"
          android:layout_width="70dp"
          android:background="#FF0000"
          android:paddingLeft="25dp"
          android:paddingRight="25dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/llMain"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >

      <View
          android:id="@+id/view"
          android:layout_width="16dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
          android:background="@drawable/vetical_rounded_corner_orange_background"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toTextView"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fromTextView"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/fromTextView"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:text="Sector 39A, Sector 32, Sector 39, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201303"
          android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/toTextView"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:text="Sector 39A, Sector 32, Sector 39, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201303"
          android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fromTextView"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fromTextView"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fromTextView"
          />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/from_dot_view"
          android:layout_width="8dp"
          android:layout_height="8dp"
          android:src="@drawable/current_location"
          android:tint="@color/white"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fromTextView"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fromTextView"
          />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/to_dot_view"
          android:layout_width="8dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/pin_red"
          android:tint="@color/white"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toTextView"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toTextView"
          />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDateTime"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="23rd jan,2016    2.30 pm"
          android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toTextView"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toTextView"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
          />
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView11"
          android:layout_width="16dp"
          android:layout_height="16dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDateTime"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clock_white_24dp"
          />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vehicleContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/sp_10"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_5"
        >

      <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
          android:id="@+id/imgVechicleImage"
          android:layout_width="48dp"
          android:layout_height="48dp"
          android:src="@drawable/imgcar_fullsize"
          tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
          tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="38dp"
          />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVichecleModel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="Camaro 45"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRegisterationNo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
            android:text="Reg no. 1234"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />


      </LinearLayout>

      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
          >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgRideIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:src="@drawable/driver"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/matchCountTextView"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fill_circle_red"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imgRideIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
            />

      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/matchesTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="You have 12 matches available"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />


    <!--<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_invite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Invite"
        app:font="MontserratRegular"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonStartEnd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FF8A65"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:text="Start Ride"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

  </LinearLayout>

  </com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

DisplayMyRideFragmentViewHolder

```
    package com.techugo.buno.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.techugo.buno.ActivityNavigator;
import com.techugo.buno.R;
import com.techugo.buno.activities.NewRideActivity;
import com.techugo.buno.activities.RatePassengersActivity;
import com.techugo.buno.app.MyApplication;
import com.techugo.buno.callbacks.RetrofitCallback;
import com.techugo.buno.common.BaseViewHolder;
import com.techugo.buno.common.events.HideLoadingEvent;
import com.techugo.buno.common.events.RefreshDependenciesEvent;
import com.techugo.buno.common.events.ShowLoadingEvent;
import com.techugo.buno.constant.AppConstant;
import com.techugo.buno.constant.ServerConstants;
import com.techugo.buno.dialog.RateDriverDialog;
import com.techugo.buno.helpers.AppUtilis;
import com.techugo.buno.home.events.ShowAddNameDialogEvent;
import com.techugo.buno.home.searchrides.SearchRideFragmentViewHolder;
import com.techugo.buno.home.sharerides.RidesAdapter;
import com.techugo.buno.loginsignup.models.User;
import com.techugo.buno.modals.NotificationResponseModel;
import com.techugo.buno.modals.UpcomingPromoModel;
import com.techugo.buno.modals.UpcomingResultModel;
import com.techugo.buno.networkInterFace.RetrofitApiService;
import com.techugo.buno.offers.OffersActivity;
import com.techugo.buno.ridedetail.Ride;
import com.techugo.buno.ridedetail.events.RideDetailEvents;
import com.techugo.framework.helper.TUGPrefs;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class DisplayMyRideFragmentViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<List<Ride>> {

    @Inject
    RetrofitApiService retrofitApiService;
    @Inject @Named("currentLoggedInUser")
    User user;
    @Inject
    ActivityNavigator activityNavigator;
    @BindView(R.id.upcomingRidesRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.emptyLayout)
    LinearLayout emptyLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.text_no_internet_connection)
    TextView noInternetTextView;
    @BindView(R.id.loading_layout) LinearLayout progressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.promo_card_view)
    CardView promoCard;
    @BindView(R.id.promo_title) TextView promoTitle;

    private RidesAdapter ridesAdapter;
    private List<Ride> myRidesModels;
    private UpcomingPromoModel myPromoModel;


    public DisplayMyRideFragmentViewHolder(View view, List<Ride> data, Context context) {
        super(view,data,context);
        this.myRidesModels = data;
        this.context = context;
        setUpRecyclerView();
        setData(myRidesModels);
    }

    private void getUpComingRides() {
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("method", ServerConstants.ALL_UPCOMING_RIDES);
        params.put("user_id", user.getUser_id());
        params.put("offset", "0");
        params.put("limit", "20");
        emptyLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ShowLoadingEvent(DisplayMyRideFragmentViewHolder.this.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        //DisplayUtils.disableUserInteraction((Activity)context);
        retrofitApiService.getUpComingRides(params)
                .enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<UpcomingResultModel>() {
                    @Override protected void onSuccess(UpcomingResultModel upcomingResultModel) {
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        EventBus.getDefault()
                                .post(new HideLoadingEvent(
                                        DisplayMyRideFragmentViewHolder.this.getClass().getSimpleName()));
                        //DisplayUtils.enableUserInteraction((Activity)context);
                        myRidesModels.clear();
                        myRidesModels.addAll(upcomingResultModel.getData());
                        if(upcomingResultModel.getOffers() != null && upcomingResultModel.getOffers().size() > 0) {
                            myPromoModel = upcomingResultModel.getOffers().get(0);
                            promoCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            promoTitle.setText(myPromoModel.getPromo_title());
                        } else {
                            promoCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        TUGPrefs.putString(AppConstant.IS_ANY_ACTIVE,
                                upcomingResultModel.getActive_ride_status());
                        initializeView(myRidesModels);
                    }

                    @Override protected void onError(String errorMessage) {
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //DisplayUtils.enableUserInteraction((Activity)context);
                        EventBus.getDefault()
                                .post(new HideLoadingEvent(
                                        DisplayMyRideFragmentViewHolder.this.getClass().getSimpleName()));
                        Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (!AppUtilis.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            emptyLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            noInternetTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        ridesAdapter = new RidesAdapter(myRidesModels, context);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
       // recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ridesAdapter);
       // ridesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    @Override
    protected void attachListeners(List<Ride> data) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeView(@NonNull List<Ride> data) {

        if (ridesAdapter != null && data.size() != 0) {
            emptyLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ridesAdapter.setData(data);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        noInternetTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void refreshView() {
        MyApplication.getInstance().getNetComponent().inject(this);
        getUpComingRides();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.fab_search_ride) void onShareRideFabClick() {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(context, FindRideActivity.class);
        //context.startActivity(intent);

        //if (user.getSignin_type().equals("1") && user.getReg_process().equals("0")) {
        //  AppUtilis.goToActivity(context, PhoneVerifyActivity.class);
        //  TUGPrefs.putString("ISFINDRIDE", "yes");
        //} else {
        //
        //}
        if (user.getFull_name() == null || user.getFull_name().isEmpty()) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ShowAddNameDialogEvent());
            return;
        }

        activityNavigator.startActivity(context, NewRideActivity.class);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.promo_card_view) void onPromoCardClick() {
        activityNavigator.startActivity(context, OffersActivity.class);
    }

    @Override public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        refreshView();
    }

    @Override public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onReloadComponents(RefreshDependenciesEvent event) {
        MyApplication.getInstance().getNetComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onRideRefresh(RideDetailEvents.RefreshRideDetailEvent event) {
        refreshView();
        String noty_retrieve = TUGPrefs.getString(AppConstant.IS_RATE_HAS_VALUE, "");
        if (noty_retrieve.length() > 0) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<NotificationResponseModel>() {
            }.getType();
            NotificationResponseModel notificationResponseModel = gson.fromJson(noty_retrieve, type);

            if (notificationResponseModel != null) {
                if (notificationResponseModel.getUser_type() != null
                        && notificationResponseModel.getUser_type().equalsIgnoreCase("Driver")) {
                    Intent intent =
                            activityNavigator.getIntent(context, RatePassengersActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstant.NOTY_PASSANGER_DATA, noty_retrieve);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    new RateDriverDialog(context, notificationResponseModel).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Toast is working but constructor is not doing anything

Comment: What does the constructor invocation do?

Comment: It is binding the viewholder of the recyclerview on which this swipe layout is

Comment: can you post more code , i want to test it!

Comment: Edited... please check